# Using DLL for web project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

I am a little new to VB.NET but I have downloaded and installed VS Express 2012 for web. I created a web application that is fairly simple. One page. `mypage.aspx` It runs perfect in studio and responses how I would expect.

What I want to do is make it run from the dll. Not from the `mypage.aspx.vb`. I see the dll for the project in the `bin` folder.

But when I move `mypage.aspx` and `web.config`, and `bin` with dll to the server it simply says its missing the code behind page. Do I just need to change the reference to the VB file?

Comment: you should publish application, not just copy.

Comment: its not actually being publish to a webserver. Its for a home automationg project. Which supprts exactly what I want to do. I just dont know how to tell it do use the dll. Also using .net 2.0

Comment: you use IIS Express? So publish to your virtual directory location. Or you can just publish to any folder on hard drive and then copy content of this folder to virtual directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use dll, Go to **Build** menu in your Visual Studio and click on **Publish Web Site**

Set Target Location, there your whole project will be get created with dll and without code behind files.

Use this project to deploy on your server.

Comment: I am such a neewb. Thanks to all.

Comment: Actually now when I do that i get an error: Could not load type projectname.project class

Comment: Added an assembly reference in the aspx page. now error is gone but nothing prints out on the page that its told to. Works perfect in Studio.

Comment: but did you build the solution?

Comment: yes I built it. Published it. Thencopied it over to the server. It ran with no errors but the response.write that is in the code dll did nothing. It ran in studio though